# How to specify the file path when one of folder starts with '.' [dot]

Tags: java, file, path

In our project we are using Jenkins and default workspace of Jenkins is c:/user/.../Jenkins/.jenkins

There are option to change the default workspace in Jenkins, but when I give absolute path to access the file, it says file not found in path even file is there.

JENKINS_HOME: c:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins

Now, when i clone the Git repository, it gets downloaded to one of folders in JENKINS_HOME path.

c:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\XXXXTestAutomation\

Code

```
File file = new File("c:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Local\\Jenkins\\.Jenkins\\workspace\\XXXXTestAutomation\\Source\textfile.txt")
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

It throws error, file not found in path. Reason is because it's not recognizing the '.Jenkins' [dot in start of folder.] Specifying a path to some other location where folder doesn't have a name works fine.

How to handle file path in Java when you have the folder name starting '.' [dot]
file.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: The _JENKINS_HOME_ value uses "Jenkins.jenkins", and the Java code uses "Jenkins\\.Jenkins".  Try removing the double slash, in the Java code.